# How to publish modules which are actually changed in gradle instead of all(not changed) to setup CI?

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-3.0

I am setting up the CI model for one project.This project is almost having 500 modules approx.We just update the workspace everytime through our CI tool and build modules which is actually changed.We are using gradle to build all modules my requirement is to publish only those modules which are changed in the current build to nexus snapshot repository.I know there is gradle task to publish the artifacts but only to publish to changed modules is the requirement.

Below is the example.

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

If there is a change in B and F then I want to publish only B and F modules in nexus and if change is in A and F then publish only A and F module.

Something similar to

```
 class IncrementalReverseTask extends DefaultTask {
      @InputDirectory
      def File inputDir

      @OutputDirectory
      def File outputDir

      @TaskAction
      void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
          if (!inputs.incremental)
              project.delete(outputDir.listFiles())

          inputs.outOfDate { change ->
              def targetFile = project.file("$outputDir/${change.file.name}")
              targetFile.text = change.file.text.reverse()
          }

          inputs.removed { change ->
              def targetFile = project.file("$outputDir/${change.file.name}")
              if (targetFile.exists()) {
                  targetFile.delete()
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I tried in below way and getting this issue

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'core'
            version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            from components.java

    }
    }
    repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "abcde"
            password "***********"
            }
            url "https://nexus.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots"
            }
            }
    }

task incrementalPublishToMavenRepository(type: IncrementalPublishToMavenRepository) {
  inputDir = file('.')
  publication = project.tasks.getByPath(":${project.name}:publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository").publication
}

class IncrementalPublishToMavenRepository extends org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository {
    @InputDirectory
    def File inputDir

    @OutputDirectory
    File generatedFileDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/libs")

    @TaskAction
    void perform(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
        println 'hello this should be executed ones'
    }
}
```

and getting below error

```
gradle jar incrementalPublishToMavenRepository

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:classes UP-TO-DATE
:app:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:app:incrementalPublishToMavenRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:incrementalPublishToMavenRepository'.
> The 'repository' property is required

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do it with maven-publish plugin

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'core'
            version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
        credentials {
            username "abcedf"
            password "***********"
            }
            // change to point to your repo, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            url "https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
}


task incrementalPublishToMavenRepository(type: IncrementalPublishToMavenRepository) {
  inputDir = file('src')
  publication = project.tasks.getByPath(":${project.name}:publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository").publication
  repository = project.tasks.getByPath(":${project.name}:publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository").repository
}

class IncrementalPublishToMavenRepository extends org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository {
    @InputDirectory
    def File inputDir

    @OutputDirectory
    File generatedFileDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/libs")

    @TaskAction
    void perform(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
        println 'hello this should be executed ones'
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
gradle jar incrementalPublishToMavenRepository
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:classes UP-TO-DATE
:app:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:app:incrementalPublishToMavenRepository UP-TO-DATE
:core:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:core:incrementalPublishToMavenRepository UP-TO-DATE
```

Here is the output if I make a change in app module the it just upload the app and say UP-TO-DATE for core module

```
gradle jar incrementalPublishToMavenRepository
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileJava
:app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:classes
:app:jar
:app:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:app:incrementalPublishToMavenRepository
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20170609.180436-15.jar
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20170609.180436-15.jar.sha1
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20170609.180436-15.jar.md5
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20170609.180436-15.pom
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20170609.180436-15.pom.sha1
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-20170609.180436-15.pom.md5
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.md5
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/maven-metadata.xml
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/maven-metadata.xml.sha1
Upload https://repo.test.com/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/app/maven-metadata.xml.md5
hello this should be executed ones
:core:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:core:incrementalPublishToMavenRepository UP-TO-DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Each task in Gradle has inputs and outputs properties to enable [incremental task capabilities](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/custom_tasks.html#incremental_tasks), so this capability could be configured for [publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/publishing_maven.html) task to publish artifacts to repository.

**Update**:

Well, to implement full solution more effort is required, however here is an idea how you can use mentioned capabilities:

```java
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

class IncrementalPublishToMavenLocal extends org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenLocal {
    @Input
    int fileCount = 10

    @OutputDirectory
    File generatedFileDir = project.file("${project.buildDir}/libs")

    @TaskAction
    void perform(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
        println 'hello this should be executed ones'
    }
}

task incrementalPublishToMavenLocal(type: IncrementalPublishToMavenLocal) {
  publication = project.tasks.getByPath(":${project.name}:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal").publication
}
```

Now you can use `./gradlew incrementalPublishToMavenLocal` to perform incremental publishing. Hope this will help to move forward.

Comment: 's can u give me one example?

Comment: @ webdizz As per my understanding you are saying in above example if the filecount is more than 10 the task publication should execute.in my case it should not only filecount but could be change in the contents as well and module will build again.

Comment: Count is just an example, you can implement resource modification check to fulfill your use case.

Comment: can I write a wrapper script which I will apply to all modules so than I don't need to write the logic in every module. I updated my question where I added some code which should help me if code is out-of-date

Comment: Can I publish the artifact in nexus instead of maven local?

Comment: Right, you just need to use proper task provided by Gradle for this repository.

Comment: Can you give me the direction where I can find this?

Comment: Invoke this command `gradle tasks --all` you will get list of convention based tasks created by Gradle per repository and publication according to documentation provided earlier.

Comment: I tried to make the change but no luck and getting the error.I updated my current post with new code and error.It is saying repository property is required.Could you please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: I am able to achieve this and also updated my answer but just want to achieve one more thing.I am giving src as my input.Is it possible to provide more than one input?How?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to skip the uploadArchives method in below way when it is not creating the jar file

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       mavenDeployer {
             repository(url: "https://repo.test.com/nexus/repos/snapshots") {
             authentication(userName: "abcdef", password: "******")
}
             pom.version = "1.1-SNAPSHOT"
             pom.groupId = "com.test"
       }
    }
}
uploadArchives {
  onlyIf { jar.didWork }
}

}
```

Below is the output when I run with clean

```
:app:clean
:core:clean
:core:compileJava
:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
:core:classes
:core:jar
:app:compileJava
:app:processResources
:app:classes
:app:jar
:app:copyLicense
:app:startScripts
:app:distTar
:app:distZip
:app:uploadArchives
:core:uploadArchives
```

Below is the output when run without clean

```
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:classes UP-TO-DATE
:app:jar UP-TO-DATE
:app:copyLicense UP-TO-DATE
:app:startScripts UP-TO-DATE
:app:distTar UP-TO-DATE
:app:distZip UP-TO-DATE
:app:uploadArchives SKIPPED
:core:uploadArchives SKIPPED
```